# phpass lengths changed significantly

Tags: php, phpass

I'm using phpass at the moment but since I've swapped computers, the length of the passwords stored has changed. I'm doing work on the localhost and recreated the database rather than exporting/importing as I was only just starting anyway.

So essentially I've just reused the same code but am now using a different (thought still the same values, tables etc) database.

The first time though the passwords looked like `$2a$08QWasd1234FqrgA54gWERGw4$ijy2`

They were rather long.

The second time around though, they look like this `$2a$08$nUkQ`

Why is this and how much of a concern should it be?

Comment: Does your db field have a too short length limit?

Comment: Well this is highly embarrassing. Yes, you are correct.